# How are the usual measurement in quantum mechanics related to the description of interaction by Feynman diagrams?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, feynman-diagrams, probability

Try to formulate the question more clearly. Using Feynman diagrams, the amplitude of particle interaction is calculated, and through it, the probability of detecting this interaction in an experiment.

But there are other types of observations, for example, measuring the location of an electron. It is well known that the probability of finding an electron in a given region of space is equal to the square of the modulus of the electron wave function. That is, the probability amplitude directly answers the question about the probability of detecting an electron.

The very concept of "detection" means that the electron interacts with the particles of the measuring device. Here the Feynman diagram method and the interaction amplitude come into force. Do I understand correctly that the wave function of the electron is somehow related to the amplitude of the probability of interaction with the particles of the measuring device, and each such amplitude can be calculated using Feynman diagrams?

It turns out that there is something unambiguous in quantum mechanics! The point is that the interaction of quantum particles either occurs (with some probability) or does not occur. But there is never a superposition <happens + does not happen>.

Comment: Feynman diagrams compute correlation functions, nothing more. That is, expectation values of operators. The S-matrix is an operator which contains all the information about scattering (which is distinct from general system states). In particular, the S-matrix allows the computation of scattering cross-sections. The LSZ reduction gives an algorithm for expressing the S-matrix in terms of correlation functions. Thus, Feynman diagrams are a tool for computing scattering data (aside from correlations). That is all.

Comment: I can’t figure out the content of your question. You know from the very postulates of QM that if you measure a certain observable it has definite probabilities that add classically, and if you’re not measuring it, the amplitudes add coherently.

Comment: @kaylimekay If no one measures the process of interaction of two electrons, then the amplitudes <electrons did not interact> and <electrons interacted> also add up coherently?

Comment: Yes, the MSW effect is a dramatic example of this (for neutrinos).

Comment: @@kaylimekay But how is this dualism to be understood? At the quantum level, there are no probabilities, but they appear as soon as the quantum world manifests itself in the classical one.

Comment: For that, I suggest to read about density matrices and decoherence. I'm sorry to not provide a more complete answer, but this is a separate question. But I think if you search for such terms you will find some relevant information.